# Loop for writing multiple dataframes to excel files in R

Tags: r

I have been splitting up dataframes and writing them to txt files in R, but now I've found out that they need to be written to xlsx files.  I installed the xlsx package and modified my loop, but it doesn't work anymore.  I get "Error in `[[.default`(dots[[2L]], 1L) : subscript out of bounds".

Here is the loop:

```
trts<-vector("list", length=6)
trt<-as.character(c("CC", "CCW", "C2", "S2", "PF", "P"))

for(i in 1:6){
trts[[i]]<-co2[co2$trt == trt[i],]
  write.xlsx(trts[[i]], paste(trt[i], "CO2", "xlsx", sep="."))
```

Here is the data (my df is co2): [Split this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kixhbzsr8xvlla6/Observed%20COBS%20CO2.txt).

What's the deal?

Comment: What is the problem actually?

Comment: Sorry, I get "Error in `[[.default`(dots[[2L]], 1L) : subscript out of bounds".

Comment: Usually that happens if you do something like `List[[7]]` for a `list` of `length < 7` or something. Try adding `print(i)` as a line in your loop and see if you can figure out which one is giving you the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Senor O, but I'm not sure I understand what is printed.  It is just the numbers 1,2,3.  I thought it would go up to six.  But this exact codes works when making txt files, just not for excel files.

Comment: Exactly - it would go up to 6 if your loop worked correctly. Now you know that your loop stops working sometime in between `print(3)` and `print(4)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just output it as CSV?

```
#Read Data
co2 <- read.table("~/Observed COBS CO2.txt",
                                header=T, quote="\"")

#Output to CSV
apply(as.matrix(unique(co2$trt)),1,
      function(x){
        write.table(co2[co2$trt == x,],
                    paste(x, "co2",".csv",sep=""),
                    sep=",",row.names=F)}
      )
```

Comment: I guess because with a .csv the person using excel won't be able to just double click on it and open it.  They have to go through the extra steps of telling excel that it is a .csv.  I'll end up with about 50 files, so I'm hoping R can make things smoother for that person.  Thanks for the non-loop code though!

Comment: Double clicking on `.csv` file just opens same way as any Excel file.

Comment: Yeah! That's what I thought, but other .csv files I have written from R are opening with all of my text in the first column.  I haven't run your code yet, but I'll try that and see if it clears up the problems I didn't know I was having before I tried .xlsx.

Comment: Yep! Thanks a lot!  Wonder why I have been using .txt anyway. . .

Comment: If it was helpful, upvoting would help.